# Array XML encoding

Tags: java, xml, encode

I am trying to encode an `Object[][]` array to an XML file but ignore some `null` elements.

For example when encoding this:

```
private Object[][] tabledata = {
        { "1", "1", "2001", "101", "151" },
        { "2", "2", "2002", "102", "152" },
        { "3", "3", "2003", "103", "153" },
        { "4", "4", "2004", "104", "154" },
        { null, null, null, null, null }, };
```

it should encode it as if it was this array:

```
private Object[][] tabledata = {
        { "1", "1", "2001", "101", "151" },
        { "2", "2", "2002", "102", "152" },
        { "3", "3", "2003", "103", "153" },
        { "4", "4", "2004", "104", "154" }, };
```

I have attempted to remove the null elements using `ArrayUtils.removeElement(Object o)` but it seems to work for uni-dimensional arrays only, XStream didn't help much either.

Should I give up encoders and go element by element using [`org.w3c.dom.Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) and the rest of the Java parsers suite?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it.

Converted to `ArrayList`, removed `nulls`, created new smaller array using the `ArrayList` and now I can just encode that :).

```
ArrayList<Object> mid = new ArrayList<Object>();
int rows = tabledata.length;
int cols = tabledata[0].length; // assuming rows >= 1
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if (tabledata[i][j] != null) {
            mid.add(tabledata[i][j]);
        } else {

        }

    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < mid.size(); i++) {
    mid.remove(null);
}
System.out.println(mid);
Object[][] inter = new Object[tabledata.length - 1][tabledata[0].length];// one
                                                                            // row
                                                                            // smaller
System.out.println(tabledata.length - 1);
System.out.println(tabledata[0].length);
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < inter.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < inter[0].length; j++) {
        inter[i][j] = mid.get(count);
        count++;
    }
}

tabledata = null;
tabledata = inter;
```